# Creating libraries that need reference to main program

Tags: c#, dll

I have a build engine which I am adding customisation to.

The customisation I am adding is in the form of a library which contains functions specific to Subversion.

My problem is, now I have separated this functionality into a main exe and several dll's, this dll requires a reference to some of the classes inside the main project (exe).

For example:

My Build Engine program contains a 'Project Class'.

The SVN dll has a function with signature:

```
SVNSourceControl(Project project, Logger logger)
```

I instantiate the SVN class with a reference to the Project I build as well as a Logger that carries out the logging for me.

The logger is fine as I have separated that into another dll and added references.

1. Do I need to separate my 'project' class into a separate dll and add references?
2. Do I need to add a reference to my dll which is the reference to my main exe and the classes within it?
3. Do I need to re-code the library to get round it some how? (Hopefully not :))

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do would be to create an interface for your `Project` class that exposes the parts of `Project` that you need access to in your library:

```
public interface IProject
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

Then change your `SVNSourceControl()` method to accept the interface instead of the class:

```
SVNSourceControl(IProject project, Logger logger)
```

Once that's done, all that's left is to define `Project` in your main exe as implementing `IProject`:

```
public class Project : myDllNamespace.IProject
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    // Whatever else
}
```

This is assuming that the dll containing the `IProject` interface and `SVNSourceControl()` method are already added as a reference to the main dll. If that's not true, you'll have to do that as well.